# SQL Server Management Studio - execute just one query, not whole script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

This has surely been asked before, sorry. But in SQL Server Management Studio v17.4, if you just hit F5, it executes the whole script.

How can you make it execute just the current line/statement? Otherwise I have to highlight the whole thing. I do this so many times a day it gets tiring.

Thanks!

Comment: Highlighting is only way.
Try to split your script into diff files, and open them in diff taps. Then you avoid multiple highlighting/searching/scrolling

Comment: Highlight the statement, press F5.  Otherwise, how do you think SSMS can magically know which line to start and which line to stop???

Comment: Eric, Dbeaver magically knows. I have many queries in a script, and put the cursor inside the block anywhere. It looks at line breaks in between queries. I hit F5 and it just runs that query, not the whole thing.

Comment: You could copy the script into its own tab and run from there. F5 will run queries in a selection or the entire editor window. There is whitespace between where the breakpoints go and the editor window. You may select and drag the mouse on that area to select whole lines as well.  Or simply put the cursor at the top of the query and go to the last line and shift+click then F5.

Answer (score 7):

Highlighting the entire query you want to execute is the only way.

Comment: This should be suitable in comment.

Comment: No, comments are for requesting clarification.   It drives me NUTS when people answer simple questions in comments and then the question never gets closed.

Comment: . . . . K. but for me the best place would be comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the script you want to execute.

By default if nothing is selected the IDE runs everything.